# Chrome and jquery css not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a dynamic element, apply some `css` on it from an external `css` file, and access the properties with `jQuery`. It works on Firefox but it does not on `Chrome`.

Here is an example :

CSS file (myFile.css):

```
.myClass {
    width : 200px;
    font-family : Verdana;
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

javascript code in a different file (myFile.js):

```
var title = $("<p/>").attr({id: "myId"}).addClass("myClass").appendTo(content);    
var titW = title.width();
var titFSize = parseInt(title.css("fontSize"));
var titFFamily = title.css("fontFamily");
console.log(titW, titFSize, titFFamily); // Firefox returns good values, Chrome does not
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/jhky5/. What does Chrome return for you?

Comment: I think the css file is not loading fast enough... If I use a setTimeout with a delay of 100ms, and try to get the properties again, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've got the answer based on your comment. You need to enclose all your jQuery code in a DOMReady event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // jQuery code goes here
});
```

This ensures that the Document Object Model (DOM) will be fully ready before it runs.

The 100ms delay you mentioned in your comment isn't a good idea, because you don't know that the stylesheet will always load in 100ms.

Comment: That's very strange. The DOM-ready event shouldn't fire until the CSS has loaded. Can you isolate the problem (write the smallest subset of your page which still causes the problem) then share it?